# MG 996R servo Raspberry Pi angle control

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, pwm, servo

I am using an MG 996R servo connected to a Raspberry Pi and an external power supply. I am using this code:

```cpp
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

servoPIN = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50) # GPIO 17 for PWM with 50Hz
p.start(2.5) # Initialization
try:
  while True:
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(12.5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(2.5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  p.stop()
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

But all I get is a continuous rotation with some random slowing downs.

My aim is to be able to rotate +90 and -90 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some MG996R servos](http://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995-robot-servo-360-180-rotation/) have been modified for *continuous rotation*. This means that what you send it doesn't set the angle, but the direction and speed of rotation.

I suspect you have one of those modified servos.

Strangely, [here's a post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78970/servo-acting-weirdly) of somebody having about the opposite problem with the same type of servo.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I got from the electronics shop when I went back to them with the problem. He gave me another servo with exact same name and descriptions on it and it works for 90 degrees.